# How do I make mobs slowly respawn up to a certain cap?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am currently making a Legend of Zelda themed adventure map. I am struggling to make it, so enemies spawn every few minutes but not spawn large amounts over time. I have tried using things like hopper clocks to time when enemies spawn but after a while it turns into a large swarm of unwanted enemies. I am looking to make it so if an enemy has already spawned another will not spawn.

Example: if there are 5 enemies in a room, there will never be more than 5. So even if a few are killed, a few minutes later more will respawn, but no more than 5 in total.

Comment: Years ago I was watching Vechs talk about making his maps and how Mojang had included spawner options. They could spawn NBT-adjusted monsters like charged creepers, from farther away, with little to no spin-up.

If such a thing still exists and hasn't been merged into commands, you may be able to use a spawner, which will not spawn more than X creatures, with a stupidly large radius.

Leaving this as a comment because I don't have enough useful info.

Comment: @FinAndTonic is making a good point, I've added the spawner method to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### using commands

You can store the result of the `execute if entity` subcommand to count how many entities there are and then execute based on that.

You will need a dummy scoreboard objective (let's say `count`) and a fakeplayer to store the amount in (let's say `$zombies`).

Now we can count the amount of zombies and only summon another one if there are 4 or less zombies in total:

```
execute store result score $zombies count if entity @e[type=zombie]
execute if score $zombies count matches ..4 run summon zombie
```

### using a spawner block

As @FindAndTonic points out correctly, there is a block in the game that is build for this specific purpose, and we can modify said block to do what we want it to do. It's the [`spawner` block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Monster_Spawner).

It can be set up in a number of ways, the only important limitation
to keep in mind is that all values are centered around the spawner block itself and that the spawn location is 1 block below to 1 block above the spawner.

Here is an example command that creates a zombie spawner that activates when the player gets in a 16 block radius of it, spawns one zombie every 5 seconds (100 ticks) in a 4 block (square) radius until there are 5 zombies max.

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ spawner{SpawnCount:1,SpawnRange:4,MinSpawnDelay:100,MaxSpawnDelay:100,MaxNearbyEntities:5,RequiredPlayerRange:16,SpawnData:{entity:{id:"minecraft:zombie"}}} replace
```